# How to access a live object in another session in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, session

A script is scheduled to run every 10 minutes to get stats from a remote resource.
The script first gets an object representing a connection to the resource (an expensive operation) and then gets stats from that object (quick op):

```
$con = get-connectionToRemoteResource  # expensive op
$res = get-stats $con  # quick op
```

Question: Is it possible to create the $con object once, and then access it in subsequent invocations of the script? . This would increase performance greatly.

I guess this would be an object running in its own session. I haven't found anything on how to access an existing object running in a different session.

Edit:

To make it clearer, I have something like this in mind:

1. Run a script init_script.ps1 to create an object and cache it somewhere or put it in some kind of object repository.
2. Some time later run a different script that would somehow have access to the object, created in step 1. So the object would only be created once and reused, not created every time from scratch.

Any ideas appreciated.

Mikey

Comment: Is [Dot Sourcing](http://ss64.com/ps/source.html) an option at all?  Not seeing the rest of your script presents the question of whether the scope would be appropriate or not.

Comment: @gravity I don't think this has anything to do with scope. The issue is accessing an object that was created in a different Powershell session.The code above is pseudo code to illustrate the general problem. I'll edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: No, it doesn't (not necessarily).  My point is that sourcing this `$connection` first would allow the connection to (possibly) remain open and useful to subsequent scripts... but it's also possible it might not, it depends on what all you intend to do with the connection.